# Indexing over the last axis when you don't know the rank in advance

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

How can I index the last axis of a Numpy array if I don't know its rank in advance?

Here is what I want to do: Let `a` be a Numpy array of unknown rank. I want the slice of the last `k` elements of the last axis.

If `a` is 1D, I want

```
b = a[-k:]
```

If `a` is 2D, I want

```
b = a[:, -k:]
```

If `a` is 3D, I want

```
b = a[:, :, -k:]
```

and so on.

I want this to work regardless of the rank of `a` (as long as the rank is at least 1).

The fact that I want the last `k` elements in the example is irrelevant of course, the point is that I want to specify indices for whatever the last axis is when I don't know the rank of an array in advance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
b = a[..., -k:]
```

This is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#structural-indexing-tools).