# What is a good way to access the "last" [...,-1] dimension of a numpy array when it might be 0-D?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

What is a good way to access the last ("-1") dimension of a numpy array, say X, when X.ndim can be equal to either 0 (i.e. X is effectively a scalar) or a positive integer (1,2,3)? I am trying to write a generalized function that takes either a scalar or an array of initial values, and does something with them over iterations.

Is there a way to neatly extend the answer given here: [Numpy: Indexing over the last axis when you don't know the rank in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916029/numpy-indexing-over-the-last-axis-when-you-dont-know-the-rank-in-advance) ? It worked perfectly for all cases except the 0D case.

I am currently getting an Index Error (*IndexError: too many indices for array*) with the following minimal example:

```
n = 0.1
n = np.asarray(n)
n = n[...,-1]
```

Comment: A 0d can only be indexed with `x[()]` or `x[...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution is to never allow 0-d arrays.  They cause strange errors like this.

Instead of using `np.array(a)`, if you expect that you might get a singleton input,  use `np.atleast_1d(a)`, which returns `array([2])` for `a = 2`, and can be indexed as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of dimensions at runtime with `ndim`, for example:

```
import numpy as np

def get_last_dim(arr):
    if arr.ndim==1:
        return arr
    else:
        return arr[:,-1]

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

print(get_last_dim(a))
print(get_last_dim(b))
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! I have to deal with this several times though, so it was simpler/cleaner to implement the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n = 0.1
>>> n = np.asarray(n)
>>> n = np.atleast_1d(n)[...,-1]
>>> n
array(0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate you explicitly showing me how I could implement it. I accepted the other answer for the explanation, but your answer was helpful.